# Can all Android/iPhone devices run any Cordova app by default?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, mobile-development

I am learning to program in `apache-cordova`. If I create a platform independent mobile application in `apache cordova`, does my Android or iPhone require to download any special packages to run the cordova app?

Can all Android/iPhone devices run a cordova app naturally with out having to download any extra plugins/packages?

Or will my clients have to download anything to their Android/iPhone devices to run my cordova app?

Thank you all in advance for the help or answers.

UPDATE : some body has negative voted my question.. So everybody please positive vote my question to give me more positive votes. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats a good question. You develop and at the end to build an release of your app. In case that you want an android and ios app, then you have to build an APK and an IPA.

But for the point of your question, no there is nothing else to download or install, just the app (APK or IPA). Cordova build apps that run "naturally" on the devices. The only difference is that normally the apps run in the appbrowser to show the webpages. If you use tools that these webpages look native, then there is for the look and feel no difference to native apps. Just filesize is little bit higher and the speed of the app a little bit slower. For actual devices is both not a problem, the CPU is powerful enough to compansate this lack of speed and filesize is for actual devices with 16 GB and more no problem at all.

I hope i answered everything, is something is missing, i´ll be here for you :)

Comment: you´re welcome. If this answer is good to you, then mark it as correct answer please. This would help other to see that this task is done. Thank you :)

Comment: thank you Kai Luck, i have marked your answer as correct. I have voted +1 for you but it wont be shown now becuase i am new user...

Answer (score 1):

You will develop as a cordova app, but for distribution, you've to package the app as either APK or IPA.

Since APKs and IPAs will be installable on Android and iOS device with min SDK, there is no need to download any specific package on client's Android/iOS device.

Comment: i have addd +1 vote for you, but it wont show now becuas i am new user and i have less than 15 points